# Hide my user control in designer form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, designer

How i can hide my user control from designer form, to show in bottom of designer, like timers or openFileDialog...

What i want to do is a custom menuStrip, with animation, progressBar, dateTimePicker, and so on. But i don't want to be visible in designer, just like normal menuStrip.

I tried to make my user control as component, but if i do it, i lose others.

An example would be :

```
public class ExampleForm : Form
{
    public ExampleForm()
    {
        CustomMenuStrip a = new CustomMenuStrip();
        a.Items.Add(new CustomMenuStripItem()
        {
            ///Stuff
        });
    }
}
public class CustomMenuStrip : UserControl
{
    public List<CustmMenuStripItem> Items;
    public CustomMenuStrip()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}

public class CustomMenuStripItem : UserControl
{
    public CustomMenuStripItem()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thank's in advance.
Andrei

Comment: Inherit your control from `System.ComponentModel.Component` instead of `UserControl`. However, why not just inherit from `MenuStrip`?

Comment: If i inherit from MenuStrip will still apear on form, and from System.ComponentModel.Component i lose all loose all Control properties, like Size, Location, BackColor, etc...

Comment: I think you are not understanding the difference between a user control and a component. A component, like the `Timer` control or `OpenFileDialog` for example, do not have a UI. `OpenFileDialog` does have a UI, but its not a UI component of the parent form. These kinds of controls that do not have a UI are the kinds that get docked to the bottom. They do not have properties, such as `BackColor` or `Size` because they have no UI.

Comment: How about ContextMenu or MenuStrip?

Comment: MenuStrip and ContextMenu are both user controls because it provides your form with an additional UI element. As such, they will derive from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and it will have properties, such as `BackColor` and `Size`.